# Why are SP objects (such as SPUser) not serializable?

Tags: object-model

I tried to create some private variables that were SPUser's, but I was given an error to the tune of 'SPUser is not marked as Serializable'.

Why?

I know these objects contain a lot of contextual information that could be invalid when deserialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be exactly what you suggest: those objects rely heavily on a valid SharePoint context in order to function.  While you can obviously use the current context to serialize an object, there is no guarantee that you will have the same context (or any context) when it is being deserialized, which would leave the new object in an unstable state.

Comment: Does it mean that I can't serialize SPFile in web service?